# Seria prudente mudar a tag do meta de stackexchange para stack-exchange?

Tags: debate, meta, meta-tags

Notei hoje a tag [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange), tem apenas 6 perguntas, no geral para uma tag não muda nada ser stackexchange ou stack-exchange, mas por uma questão de padronizar, o site e a rede tem seus nomes formados por duas palavras

> Stack Exchange

Isto é mesmo apenas por questão de padronização, claro que os domínios devem ser juntos (sem hifen) devido a facilitar para o usuário escrever.

No meta.stackexchange.com eles usam também sem hifen, mas outras coisas eles usam com hifen, por exemplo: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-snippets

Por enquanto a sugestão é apenas para o meta.pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Criar um sinônimo, talvez?

Comment: @Gabe uma boa ideia.

Comment: Eu acho que a principal tem que ser renomeada "stack-exchange", de qualquer forma. Se for só sinônimo, vai continuar sendo exibida sem traço. É preferível no meu ver que se renomeie ou recrie a tag com traço como principal, e a versão sem traço seja apenas sinônimo, para evitar o uso misturado das duas formas.

Comment: @Bacco na verdade tinha sido este o meu entendimento, mas se entendi errado, então digo que a minha opinião é a mesma que a sua.